# Unity Editor freezes very frequently

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working with Unity 2018.1.6f1 64-bit on Windows and my editor keeps freezing. This happens whenever the loader (I guess compiling scripts) appears. I checked the editor profiler and it tells me ApplicationTickTimer is taking 42708ms to finish (See image below).

[image: Picture of profiler]

This started happening not long after I implemented Firebase, but it did not show this behaviour right after I implemented it, so I doubt it has to do with that. I also always have the light baking loading bar (bottom right) in my eduitor (2D project, no lights in my scene). My colleague (who works on the same project as I) does not expierence this on his computer.

Does anyone have a clue?